# How do I converse with the people who deleted my answer?

Tags: support

I answered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2428648/2029983) with an answer based on a widely held Python community view. That answer was deleted, and I would like to know if the deleters thought the view was repeated elsewhere, (I think not). Without my answer you are left without the "We are all consenting adults" answer that has been repeated in the Python community and by some established contributors.

See below image of my answer for those with < 10k reputation.
[image]

Comment: There's no need to. Anyone with the privilege can cast undelete votes, not just those 3 users.

Comment: [This is a headscratcher](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2428648/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries).  Why would you want to edit the answer just to turn around and delete it?

Comment: Isn't your answer already covered by the other, heavily upvoted one that states `You could put a comment in there to the effect of:`

Comment: The answer could be a comment – it reads more like an opinion, and is also wrong right off the bat by saying "Yes there is" when in fact there is not. The 6 downvoters, of which I am not one, seem to have had some concerns over the usefulness of the answer as well. On a side note, if I had the opportunity to vote for deletion on the highest-scoring answer, I certainly would.

Comment: @Makoto I was just doing some cleanup of meta-commentary about downvotes in answers. Just because I vote for deletion of an answer doesn't mean others will agree. I have many delete votes that are still pending years after I cast them.

Comment: @miken32:  Sure, but it doesn't make any sense.  Editing a post means that the post has merit and value.  Deleting it declares the exact opposite.  You don't just delete content on a whim.

Comment: @Makoto editing a post means there's something about it that needs editing, and that is a separate judgement as to whether it provides value. I outlined my reasons for the delete vote in my comment above; if the community hadn't agreed with that, the post still would have benefited from the edit.

Comment: "if the deleters thought the view was repeated elsewhere" [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56353880/is-calling-a-private-variable-from-a-parent-class-as-a-child-class-violating) uses the same quote but seemingly discussed the topic in a much more thorough way.

Comment: @miken32: It is a waste of effort to polish a turd if you think it is a turd.  Either you're removing toxic content or you're fixing up useful content. There is no in-between.

Comment: @Makoto that attitude suggests I'm the sole decider of whether or not something is a turd, which I'm not ("we live in a society" as the kids like to say.) I'm aware that others might disagree, and something I think is a turd might stick around. In that case, yes: I like my turds nice and shiny!

Comment: @miken32:  No one rain drop is responsible for the flood, sure.  But there's two very different types of signals you're sending when deciding to delete a post *and* deciding to edit it.

Comment: @Makoto again, I am not "deciding" to delete a post. I'm *voting* to do so.

Comment: It is an opportunity to convert the rhetorical questions to statements. Be direct. Questions do not belong in answers.

Comment: @miken32 I very much respect the distinction you make between deciding and voting, it is exactly the kind of precision in terminology that is needed and in the haste of the moment tends to get lost causing miscommunication. It changes nothing though, Makoto's comment about sending out mixed signals which you choose to ignore stands.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To answer the titular question "How do I converse with the people who deleted my answer?":

#### Post on Meta Stack Overflow

While you may or may not reach the specific delete voters (a lot of whom are active on Meta, and others are active in places where they'll tend to hear about Meta posts regarding posts they voted to delete), you'll definitely reach people who can vote to undelete.

Make sure you explain your desired result and reasoning.  For example, you could explain why your answer should not have been deleted, or express that you're not sure why it was deleted and would appreciate an explanation of the issues with it.

Answer (score 5):

This is a bit of a tricky one, IMHO (especially, for me, because I am not – and nor do I pretend to be – a Python expert).

But, overall, I think this answer was deleted inappropriately. Maybe it's not a *good* answer, but it is every bit as much of *an* answer as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2425818/10871073) highly upvoted, other answer. Thus, I have voted to undelete.

Also, I generally feel that there is a tendency among *some* 20k+ users (though I'm not claiming this is the case here) to use a delete vote as some kind of "Super Downvote". This is not what deletion of answers is about: If you don't *like* an answer, then feel free to downvote it. However, by casting a delete vote, you are using a "Trusted User" privilege; and, as such, those votes should be used only with great caution/consideration, on answers that are clearly: (a) noise; (b) not answers (e.g., "Me too" and "Thanks"); (c) dangerous; or (d) otherwise inflicting damage on the site or on the Internet in general.

The answer under discussion, while maybe not *directly* answering the original question, does (IMHO) provide interesting (though, perhaps, controversial) insight into the issue raised.

Comment: The phrase "We are all consenting adults" comes from Guido, the creator of Python, and is a well-known expression of the Python philosophy. However, some people don't like its connotations, as mentioned here: https://github.com/realpython/python-guide/issues/525

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks. Like I said, I'm no Python guru. But, with your comment and re-reading the question, I have edited-out that part of my answer.

Comment: I agree that "it is every bit as much of an answer as this highly upvoted, other answer." but (to use makoto's terminology) just because one turd floats to the top, doesn't mean all of them should!

Comment: @PM2Ring you are saying that post should be deleted for plagiarism due to lack of attribution of that quote :) ?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Certainly not! Although it would be nice if that answer did mention that Guido is the source of that phrase, I don't think it's necessary. Similarly, people can quote statements from the Zen of Python without explicitly mentioning the source, or Tim Peters, since they're well-known within the Python community. FWIW, I voted to undelete  that answer.